# How to test RXJS utils like pipe,skip,tap,retry etc.. inside any angular app with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, rxjs, jasmine

I am trying to test my components inside an angular app using Jasmine.
I am unable to mock certain utils like a pipe, skip, switch map, etc from RXJS.
`this.route.queryParams.pipe(skip(1)).subscribe(params => comsole.log(params);`

Can someone help me suggest a way to test this piece out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are little bit on a wrong track. Let's bring you on the right way.

First of all you need to test observables like a blackbox. You don't need to know what happens in there. You only want to know what goes in and what goes out. You can test that perfectly with jasmine marble. This link might help you here:
https://medium.com/@bencabanes/marble-testing-observable-introduction-1f5ad39231c

By this blackbox principle you can test the **effect** of certain operators on your stream. You don't want to mock them. `skip(1)` for example can be testet by an in-Observable like `of(1, 2)` and expect an out-Observable `of(2)`.

What you could mock and e.g. expect toHaveBeenCalled are external ressources called within those operators, which is most likely to happen within the switchMap.